# Firebase and play services library conflict

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

This is the full error that I'm getting.

> 11-01 13:33:51.550 3932-3932/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and
>   chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system 11-01 13:34:12.744
>   3932-3991/com.example.cmd.testproject E/ActivityThread: Failed to find
>   provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera 11-01 13:34:12.745
>   3932-3991/com.example.cmd.testproject E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy:
>   NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
>                                                                                     com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable
>   module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.zzh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzchz(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 11-01 13:34:12.746
>   3932-3991/com.example.cmd.testproject E/UploadTask: Unable to create a
>   network request from metadata
>                                                                          android.os.RemoteException
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.zzh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzchz(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                              at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 11-01 13:34:12.746
>   3932-3991/com.example.cmd.testproject E/StorageException:
>   StorageException has occurred.
>                                                                                An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner
>   exception for server response.
>                                                                                 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0 11-01 13:34:12.746
>   3932-3991/com.example.cmd.testproject E/StorageException: null
>                                                                                android.os.RemoteException
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.zzh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzchz(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 11-01 13:34:12.746
>   3932-3991/com.example.cmd.testproject E/StorageException:
>   StorageException has occurred.
>                                                                                An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner
>   exception for server response.
>                                                                                 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0 11-01 13:34:12.746
>   3932-3991/com.example.cmd.testproject E/StorageException: null
>                                                                                android.os.RemoteException
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzena.zzh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzchz(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

app level build

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.cmd.testproject"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
        compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'


        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level build

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I solve this problem to use firebase storage?

Comment: Check your logcat for `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`. Your device/emulator may have on old version of Google Play services.

Comment: @BobSnyder havent found anything like that in the logcat and my emulator is up to date.

Comment: Post the code that requests the upload.